# When does $\sum a_i = \sum b_i \implies a_i = b_i$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

When does $\displaystyle \sum_i a_i = \sum_i b_i \implies a_i = b_i$?

Comment: When there is only **one** term in the sum, this is trivially true. In general, there is no canonical condition. Consider $1+2=2+1$.

Comment: If you are talking about $(a_1,\cdots, a_n)=(b_1,\cdots,b_n)$, then by definition one has $a_i=b_i$ for all $i$.

Comment: Well, you can put artificial stipulations such... I dunno.  $i < j\iff a_i < a_j \iff b_i< b_k$ and there are $5$ positive integer terms in each summand and the sums add to $16$.  ...But in general this is almost never applies.

Comment: One simple set of extra conditions that will guarantee the implication is that $\ a_i \le b_i\ $ for all $\ i\ $.

Answer (score 1):

What about

$$\sum_{i=1}^na_i=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac1i, \quad \sum_{i=1}^nb_i=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac1{n-i+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are asking when you can recover the summands from a sum.

I would say NEVER when there is more than one summand with possible exceptions given by giving extra-conditions so strong to make the fact trivial or almost trivial.

One such example, for instance, may be asking for $b_i\geq0$ such that $\sum b_i=0$ which has $b_1=b_2=\cdots=0$ as the only solution.

A slightly less trivial possibility is assuming that the $b_i$ must be logs of prime numbers. Then the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic says you can recover
the summands because the factorization of an integer as product of prime numbers is unique.